# Haskell parsec match if (3) as if (3 > 0)

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm using Parsec and the example version of boolExpr http://hpaste.org/86299 at the moment. I'm compiling on Windows via GHC.

The code above will match a boolean expression like `3 < 4` or `a not 3` however it will not match an expression like `3`, `true` or `(((3 < 1)))`. Can anyone give me advice on how to match such expressions like `3` and `(((3 < 1)))` the same as `3 > 0` and `(((3 < 1))) > 0`, where the >0 is assumed/added automatically on RHS-less expressions?

Comment: To clarify: you want to parse the string `"3"` into the same structure as `"3 > 0"`?

Comment: ie: `3 > 0` results in an expression that validates if (expr) expr; however `(3 > 0)` results in (expr), hence, for that to be valid I must be able to parse any single term inside brackets against >0 if there is no RHS. `(((3))) -> (((3 > 0) > 0) > 0) > 0` unless you know a better way to do it so that expressions like `while (1)`, `while ((1))` and `while ((x>2))` are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you're trying to push the semantics of your language into a *syntax* parser. The "correct" thing to do from a programming-languages perspective is to accept both number and boolean-valued expressions in your syntax tree. Then, at a later stage -- type reconstruction *not* parsing -- decide that number-valued expressions get a single "> 0" added to them while boolean valued expressions do not.